# Squid on a different host than gateway

Tags: squid

I have Squid running on a dedicated VM. It has ip 192.168.1.5. The server running squid has only one NIC. The internet connection is connected to another (physical) server with two nics. The internal network card of the local NIC is 192.168.1.1.

Now I have a client who needs to connect to the internet through the squid proxy, so I point the proxy setting to 192.168.1.5. I see the request in /var/log/squid. So far so good, but unfortunately Squid is somehow unable to "deliver" the internet to the client.

I think I'm missing the final step, but I can't figure out what it is. Any help is appreciated.

The situation:

```
                    ┌──────────────────┐          ┌─────────────────────┐
                    │   Squid proxy    │          │                     │
                    │      1 nic       │◀─────────│       client        │
                    │                  │          │                     │
                    └──────────────────┘          └─────────────────────┘
                              │                                          
                              │                                          
                              ▼                                          
                    ┌──────────────────┐                                 
                    │      server      │                                 
┌──────────┐        │   192.168.1.1    │                                 
│ INTERNET │───────▶│     does NAT     │                                 
└──────────┘        │      2 nics      │                                 
                    └──────────────────┘
```

The Squid host is perfectly able to connect to the internet. Network configuration of the host is like this:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
  address 192.168.1.5
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  gateway 192.168.1.1
  dns-nameservers 192.168.1.1
```

Comment: Perform packet captures in various locations. That way you'll be able to quickly determine where the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

Can you reach the internet from the Squid host (such as w/curl or something like that)? It sounds like routing from the Squid host is incorrect.  Focus on using 'curl' from the squid host and resolving its ability to reach the internet.

Also, were you experimenting with any rules on the NAT instance to prevent hosts other than squid from reaching the internet?

Comment: Yes, the Squid host is perfectly able to reach the internet through it's NIC. I have added it's /etc/network/interfaces file in the question.